# Javascript: why does this produce and ugly string??? I would like currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-formatting

```
var total = 0;
$(".amount").each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = (value.length < 1) ? 0 : value;
    var tmp = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    total += tmp;
});
$(".total").text(total);
```

I am trying to loop through some text boxes and sum up their values. This produces a nasty string. What am I missing?? if I put 8 in the first textbox total text ends up as "  08.000.000.000.00". What am I doing wrong? I would like to format as currency but if not, at least just a two decimal number. Any pointers?

Comment: what i tend to do is always do maths as floats or ints, keeping the sources as they are for any future operations. I then have a prototype coded .money(currencySign) which is used purely for display of results to end user but not in any math operations--outputs a string.

Comment: String.prototype.toMoney = function() {
        return "$ " + this;
    }

 var amount = total.toFixed(2).toMoney();
            $(".total").text(amount);
Sweet!!! Works perfect!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

.toFixed converts the object from a Number to a String.

Leave the full values in place and only convert using .toFixed at the very end

```
$(".total").text(total.toFixed(2));
```

Alternatively, convert the string back to a number.

```
total = total + + tmp;
```

Comment: ++ saved me, I was applying `.toFixed(2)` to float but that converted it to string and when adding with one `+` I got 5+5=55 instead of 5+5=10. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, there is an excellent mathematical aggregation plugin for jQuery: [jQuery Calculation](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm)

Using that plugin may also indirectly solve your issue.

It's usage would reduce your script to:

```
$('.total').text($('.amount').sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the parseFloat into a string, then adding it to total. Only add .toFixed(2) to the final line, once things have been added.

```
var total = 0;
$(".amount").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = (value.length < 1) ? 0 : value;
    var tmp = parseFloat(value);
    total += tmp;
});
$(".total").text(total).toFixed(2);
```